# Swift SpriteKit - Setting zRotation equal to angle but it is not equal

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have been working on rotating an object to a targetRotation not instantly but every 10 milliseconds it moves 1 degree. Eventually when it within 1 degree it will be set equal to the target.

What's happening is when I set the zRotation equal to the targetZRotation, and then right away log the difference between the two, it is never 0. Shouldn't it be equal.

```
if abs(difference) < TO_RADIANS {
   zRotation = targetZRotation!
   NSLog("\(zRotation - targetZRotation!)")
}
```

Comment: This is only a suggestion, and might not be of any use to you at all - once within your 1 degree range, you could set a constraint to "look at" a certain angle or target - https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skconstraint

Comment: What values the log is giving?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: no it will not be equal, zRotation uses CGFloat on the front end, then goes through a series of casts and changes on the back end to be usable with the GPU,  All of these casts cause some kind of loss in precision, which gets you your dilema.